# Sum of a sine series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am struggling to find the proof of a sine series.

The series is as follows:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(2n+1)x}{2n+1} = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$$

Note: $x \neq n\pi$

Can you help me with a proof or a direction I should look in? Thank you.

Comment: I think it is wrong. Consider the case $x=0$, and it is true when $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio I should have mentioned $x$ cannot be $n\pi$. Sorry

Comment: then, what is $n$? Natural numbers? or integers? or real number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin((2n+1)x)}{2n+1}=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x=k\pi$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$,}\\
\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot\mathrm{sign}(\sin(x)) & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Hint. Evaluate the [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Definition) of the odd function $\mathrm{sign}(x)$.