# Using Fourier Series to prove $\frac\pi4=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin{(2n-1)x}}{2n-1}$ if $0<x<\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

I want to use Fourier Series to prove this formula:
$$ \frac{\pi}{4}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin{(2n-1)x}}{2n-1} \quad\quad \text{if}\quad 0<x<\pi$$
To do this, my thought was to let $f(x)=x$ over $[0,\pi]$ and then use an odd periodic extension to define it over the interval $[0,2\pi]$. Doing this, and calculating the coefficients, I found:
$$ a_n=0 \quad\quad\quad b_n=-\frac{2}{n}\cos{n\pi}=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2}{n} $$
Since $f(x)$ is a polynomial and our interval is bounded, we know that $f$ is of bounded variation and so by Jordan's Theorem we know that we have convergence of our series to our function. So I arrive at:
$$ x = 2\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sin{nx}}{n} $$
I thought that from here I could just let $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and the formula would pop right out but I'm not so sure because then all my $\sin$ terms would actually be evaluated. I also thought maybe I overcomplicated things and could just find the Fourier Series of $f(x) = \frac{\pi}{4}$ but that would just be itself. The other thing I thought to do was maybe to extend it as an even function over the interval $[0,2\pi]$ instead, but I don't really see why I would do this when the formula I'm looking to derive only involves signs.

Any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why $f(x) = x$? The function you have a Fourier series for is constant for $0<x<\pi$ so doesn't it make more sense to try to compute the Fourier series of $f(x) = 1$ (oddly extended)?

Comment: btw this function is known as the [square wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave#Fourier_analysis)

Comment: Thanks I just tried $f(x)=1$ and was able to figure it out pretty easily

Comment: Whinther is right: see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3348065)

Comment: I have one remaining question: if I let $f(x)=1$ on $[0,\pi]$ and then use an odd extension to define it over $[-\pi,\pi]$ does the formula I find for $f(x)$ hold for all x in $[0,\pi]$ or all x in $[-\pi,\pi]$? Thanks again!

Comment: The odd extension is $f(x) = 1$ for $0 < x < \pi$ and $f(x) = -1$ for $-\pi < x < 0$ so the fourier series will converge to this function for all $-\pi < x < \pi$ (except for at the jump discontinuity at $x=0$ where it converges to $(1+(-1))/2=0$).